# How to set a defualt value for a Clarity Datepicker in Angular

Tags: angular, .net-core, clarity

I currently have a Angular 7 Project wit .Net core 2.0 and for styling if the project i use Clarity components.

**Does Anyone know how to set a default value for a clarity date-picker?**

(I'm using reactive forms in angular which also uses validations that checks if the field is not empty and not bigger than the current date.)

**What My HTML looks like:**

```
<clr-date-container>
    <label>Service Date</label>
    <input type="date" clrDate formControlName="fromDateField" 
      [clrDate]="ValidateFromDateField()" />
    <clr-control-error>{{this.errorMsgFromdate}}</clr-control-error>
  </clr-date-container>
```

**What My Component Looks Like**

```
 ValidateFromDateField() {
    if ((this.claimDetailService.DefaultDate === "") || (this.claimDetailService.DefaultDate === undefined)
      || (this.claimDetailService.DefaultDate === null)) {
     this.claimDetailService.DefaultDate = this.claimDetailform.get('fromDateField').value;
    } 
    console.log('Defualt date ', this.claimDetailService.DefaultDate);
    this.claimDetailService.currentClaimDetail.FROMDATE = new Date(this.claimDetailform.get('fromDateField').value).toDateString();
    this.claimDetailService.currentClaimDetail.TODATE = new Date(this.claimDetailform.get('fromDateField').value).toDateString();
    this.errorMsgFromdate = this.FieldValidation(this.claimDetailService.currentClaimDetail.FROMDATE, 'fromDateField');
    if (this.errorMsgFromdate === 'valid') {
      this.errorMsgFromdate = ' ';
      this.PopulateFromDateErr();
    }
    if (this.errorMsgFromdate !== '') {
      this.claimDetailform.get('fromDateField').setErrors(this.errorMsgFromdate);
    }
    this.claimDetailService.DefaultDate = this.claimDetailform.get('fromDateField').value;
  }
```

i did try using the setValue() method but it gave me an error in the console saying that setValue is not a valid property of Clarity datepicker.And the validation is done on blur but blur doesn't work on a date-picker so i used [clrDate] to call the validation method.

Comment: have you tried [(ngMode)]="currentDate" like in your code?

Comment: please accept the answer if solution worked for you so that other will get benefit out of it thanks

Comment: I have updated solution on stackblitz please check https://stackblitz.com/edit/clarity-light-theme-v11-datepicker-px6ur6?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [formControl] and bind it to your formControl created in your component.ts

```
  <clr-date-container>
   <label>Service Date</label>
   <input type="date" clrDate 
      [formControl]="myDateField" 
      id="date" name="date"
      [(ngModel)]="date"
      [clrDate]="ValidateFromDateField()" />
   <clr-control-error>{{this.errorMsgFromdate}}</clr-control-error>
</clr-date-container>
```

So in your ts component create the formControl

```
myDateField = new FormControl('');
```

And patch the value with:

```
  this.myDateField.patchValue('02/02/2019');
```

Also remember that if the date is wrong, date picker will return a null according to documentation:

```
Date picker emits null when an invalid date is entered after a valid date was set.
```

So be sure to check which of 3 format are your using because it will not parse for you any format even if is a correct date, the default of angular is:

MM/DD/YYYY

You can readme more on the Official Documentation: https://clarity.design/documentation/datepicker#examples

Comment: @Robert_It doesn't work ngModel has been removed when using with reactive froms in Angular 7...got the following error = reactive form directives has been deprecated in Angular v6 and will be removed in Angular v7.

Comment: Yes is deprecated, i tought you're using template driven form. My bad, i edited the answer. Just remove your formControlName and add [formControl] like my example.

Answer (score 0):

Here you need to bind default date to ngModel like below

```
 <form class="compact">
        <section class="form-block">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="date">Date:</label>
            <input type="date" id="date" [(ngModel)]="defaultDate" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" clrDate>
          </div>
        </section>
      </form>
```

And declare `defaultDate` in TS file

```
 defaultDate = '06/14/1989';
```

[Here is solution on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/clarity-light-theme-v11-datepicker-px6ur6?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: @TheParam_It doesn't work ngModel has been removed when using with reactive froms in Angular 7...got the following error =  reactive form directives has been deprecated in Angular v6 and will be removed 
 in Angular v7.

Comment: I think you are confused with the fact that Angular is deprecating support for ngModel to work with formControlName rather than completely deprecating ngModel

Comment: I provided solution on stackblitz please check that you wont get such warning

Comment: @TheParam_sorry i understood it incorrectly, but i'm using formControlName in my project with the Date field and all the other fields i'm using in order to do my validations

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest solution, May this will help you 
[find the stackblits link here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mafa4u)

if you want to use recative forms then you have to add `ReactiveFormsModule` in your parent module.

also you need do declare a fromGroup in html templete and assign value to the control initially as shown in the above solution.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can do as follows:

```
 this.myForm = formBuildr.group({
  myDateControl: [new Date().toLocaleDateString()]});
```

Or

```
myDateField = new FormControl(new Date().toLocaleDateString());
```